# How to change plain message into html message in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm getting string representation of html code in email.. How can i get proper html email ?

```
    message1 = (subject, 'Here is the message', from_email, recipient_list)
    message2 = (subject, html_message, from_email, recipient_list)
    message2.content_subtype =  "html" 
    send_mass_mail((message1, message2), fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: How do you want `html-message` to be (for e.g. to be wrapped in a certain html tag like `<p>Here is the message</p>`)??

Comment: yeah brother...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

```
msg = "Here is the message"

message1 = (subject, msg, from_email, recipient_list)
html_message = "<p>" + msg + "</p>"
message2 = (subject, html_message, from_email, recipient_list)
message2.content_subtype =  "html" 
send_mass_mail((message1, message2), fail_silently=False)
```

Here I declared a variable for the message `msg` which can be concatenated with the html tag you want (here it is `<p>` tag) using the concatenation operator `+`

Thank you!